Google Cloud Function deploy error: Cloud Run service ... for the function was not found
I used to be able to deploy cloud functions, but not anymore it seems.
Steps:

Click "Create function" in https://console.cloud.google.com
Leave everything default -> next -> deploy

Deployment starts and finishes with errors:

This function has failed to deploy and will not work correctly. Please edit and redeploy.
Cloud Run service projects/random-360814/locations/us-central1/services/function-1 for the function was not found. The function will not work correctly. Please redeploy.
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/c27ab140-87c0-4db8-a139-3caf65bd9fe0?project=817067604452. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/c27ab140-87c0-4db8-a139-3caf65bd9fe0?project=817067604452.

Build logs refered in the error message don't add any info


Do you have the cloud run api enabled on the project? What does the log in stackdriver says? (not the cloud build logs)

Here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/browse
Cloud Run Admin API - API Enabled
Cloud Build API -  API Enabled
Stackdriver logs have nothing interesting: only errors from google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.CloudBuild.CreateBuild without any messages and cloudfunctions.googleapis.com with "Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: An unexpected error occurred. Refer to build logs"

Hi Oleg. I think is not necessary that you shared the exact url from the project as nobody has access to it.
You are deploying Gen2 Cloud Functions right? Does it happens if you deploy Gen1 Cloud Functions?
Is it possible for you to try in another GCP project to see if the error remains?
If you change the region of the default location does it changes something?
Does the default CF service account has all of the necessary permissions?

@MrThompson both gen1 and gen2 give the same error. Changing region doesn't help either. In a new project however it works. Problem is, new project also changes the URL, which is important for the consumers of my function (which used to be online for years, until it broke recently)

upd: I disabled functions, run, build, artifacts registy apis, then enabled them back and now it works again. Thank you for the hint @MrThompson

Awesome! That usually happens when the default SA gets deleted or their permissions are removed!
